# How to make HSQL not auto update entity when change entity's field

Tags: java, hibernate, hsqldb

I have an entity and whenever I edit its field, HSQL immediately updates the entity.

The code below

```
System.out.println(userService.findById(user.getId()).getPassword());

user.setPassword("password");

System.out.println(userService.findById(user.getId()).getPassword());

userService.update(user);

System.out.println(userService.findById(user.getId()).getPassword());
```

prints out in the console

```
qwerty
password
password
```

which means that even before I use `update()`, the entity is already updated.

How can I stop it? So that entity can be only updated invoking the method, but not when you change its field.

Hibernate config:

```
jdbc.driverClassName=org.hsqldb.jdbc.JDBCDriver
jdbc.url=jdbc:hsqldb:mem:myDb
jdbc.username=sa
jdbc.password=sa
hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.HSQLDialect
hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto=create
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming you have a transaction open around the following code:

```
System.out.println(userService.findById(user.getId()).getPassword());
user.setPassword("password");
System.out.println(userService.findById(user.getId()).getPassword());
userService.update(user);
System.out.println(userService.findById(user.getId()).getPassword());
```

What happens is Hibernate fetches the entity and since it's still within a transaction the entity is a hibernate managed entity so ANY changes to the entity (e.g. user.setPassword(...) will result in those changes being flushed to the DB.

If you instead only make the userService transactional (i.e. remove the transaction from surrounding the example code and annotate the userService as @Transactional (assuming you're using Spring)) then when you do the `user.setPassword(...)` it will be OUTSIDE of a transaction and the changes won't persist.

Alternatively you can force the entity to detach (so that it's no longer managed) by calling the EntityManager::detach method.

For additional context read section 3.5 in the following link: https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/entitymanager/3.5/reference/en/html/objectstate.html

Comment: Yeah, you are right. My UserService was annotated with `@Transactional` and the class, where I used the code I showed, was annotated with `@Transactional` as well. Removing annotation in the second class helped me. Thanks!